# Is there a way to get a browser to reduce the "width" as well as the "device-width" when in device mode

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive, microsoft-edge

When I test a page in device mode in chrome (as well as Edge/Brave/Opera) the device-width property seems to be reduced, but the width property isn't

Recreate:

```
<html>
    <style>
        html {
            background-color: #EEE;
        }
        @media (min-width: 750px) {
            html {
                background-color: #BADC55;  
            }
        }
    </style>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</html>
```

Making the window small works as expected:

[image: Small window]

Device mode doesn't:

[image: Device Mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then you have to ad this line to your code

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```